# hide Required Field issue in Orchard Custom Forms

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8, orchard-modules

While developing a custom form, there is a requirement that if the end user chooses option: `Life Insurance` from the `Insurance Type` dropdownlist, as seen below: 
[image]

Then another dropdownlist will be displayed ( dynamically show/hide using Jquery ) which allows user to select the `duration` as seen below:

[image]
if the user chooses option: `Others` from the First dropdownlist [ `Insurance Type` ], we are simply hiding the SECOND dropdownlist `Duration`.

The problem is that the `Duration` dropdownlist is a required field, and When a user chooses option: `Others`, there is no value supplied for `Duration` field, since we hide this dropdownlist using Jquery.

When clicking the submit button, validation always fails since NO value for the 2nd dropdownlist: `Duration` was supplied. How can i handle this situation ?

When a required Field is hide using Jquery then Validation fails always .

Comment: I think if you have 2 fields that are depended of each other, you create a custom part and add the fields as properties instead. Then you can have the frontend as well as the backend logic to check required etc.

Comment: This also might be useful to you: http://henry-chong.com/orchard-cms-conditional-field-rendering

Comment: @devqon: Thank you for the Link. Unfortunately they didn't help. issue is that once the Form is rendered on the website, after that depending on User's selection other form elements are added/removed. and on the click of submit button, the Orchard Validation always looks for the Required Field whether they are hidden or not